# React on multi page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I created a React App on a multi page website, but I don't know how to integrate it on our website.

#### Explanation of the problem

1. The user load the website *"/"* (no react code is involved at the first loading)
2. The user click on a link *"/appReact"*
3. The _"/appReact" page loads the page and the React app code
4. The React app sends ajax requests to the server
5. Finally the React app gets the data and render itself

The step 3 and 4 makes the loading very slow.
The step 3 delay is caused by the multipage nature of the website.
The step 4 delay is caused by the response of the server

#### Possible solutions

I can try many different solutions or combine them, but I'm not sure if is the right way to proceed.

#### Optimize the react app to makes the ajax loader faster

In my case I can do that but is not the real problem.

#### Load the React app when the user load the website ("/")

This could improve the step 4, but we carry on the React app all around the website.

#### Use react router in conjunction of the multipage website

I don't know if is possible to do that. React-router can handle the url to load different apps, but I don't know if is possible to do in a multi site page without affect the site.

#### A trick using jquery

I have this temptation to bind the click (step 2) and hide the content of the page to run the react app. This will simulate a Single Page Application, but is a patch. I would like something more reliable.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Simple suggestion.. Keep jquery away from react :), You can use a bundler (webpack) to do this work. It can bundle uglify and optimize the package. Load the js file only in one specific route (not at the initial route)

Comment: server side rendering of react app for the initial loading..

Comment: The react app is compiled on the server.

Comment: You can perform the initial render on the server and then the client can continue to use the react app as normal once it has been downloaded.   Google Isomorphic React

Comment: I don't know how to render on the server. The react app is compiled js file loaded from the browser

Answer (score 1):

You could try [React Habitat](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat)

That way you can pass properties to your React App directly on page load and not need the additional ajax request.